# How do I insert a line at a line of a file in sed for windows?

Tags: sed, gnuwin32

if i have a file

```
half a pound
of tuppenny rice
half a pound
that's the way
the money goes
pop goes the weasel
```

And I want to insert a line "of treacle" at line 4. so it should be

```
half a pound
of tuppenny rice
half a pound
of treacle
that's the way
the money goes
pop goes the weasel
```

how can I do this in sed for windows. I am  using gnuwin32's sed.

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\Users\username>type afile.txt
half a pound
of tuppenny rice
half a pound
that's the way
the money goes
pop goes the weasel
C:\Users\username>

C:\>sed "4i\of treacle" afile.txt
half a pound
of tuppenny rice
half a pound
of treacle
that's the way
the money goes
pop goes the weasel
C:\>
```

you can use `sed "3a\of treacle" afile.txt`

i inserts before that line. 4i would be before line 4.
a inserts after that line. 3a would be after line 3. so, 3a is the same as 4i.